# Arabic text on masterpage is corrupted like Ù„ÙˆØ­Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹Ù„ÙˆÙ…Ø§Øª

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, master-pages

I have asp.net web application using Arabic language ,I published it and host it on Godaddy .

there is no problem when I get Arabic text from database.
But the text in master page like labels it's appear like  Ù„ÙˆØ­Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹Ù„ÙˆÙ…Ø§Øª

this problem in master page only , not for all pages , 
I tried to use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

but the text still appear like Ù„ÙˆØ­Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹Ù„ÙˆÙ…Ø§Øª  (only in masterpage)

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

open the asp page with notepad++
and try save it on other charset (ansi or utf-8)